# how to set names in left and right in \author?

Tags: beamer

when i try to set left and right side to fix content. i need to set content in below diagram . i used the package \usepackage[british]{babel},\usetheme{Rochester}

```
\author[xyz]{\footnotesize 
 Final Presentation\\ 
submitted  by\\
  xyz\\%
  Under the guidance of \\
 xyz\\
  xyz}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use two side-by-side `minipage`s. This will also require to enclose the whole construct in `\texorpdfstring` to avoid problems in bookmarks and PDF information:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}

\title{The Title}
\author[xyz]{\texorpdfstring{%
\footnotesize 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
Final Presentation \\ 
submitted  by \\
xyz
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
Under the guidance of \\
xyz \\
xyz
\end{minipage}}{The Author}}
\institute[The institute]{The Institute \\ xyz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]